# (ios) how to add subview with animation

Tags: ios, xib, caanimation

the subview is created in xib file,height is 390

```
    ITTalentShowAdvancePopUpView * view=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ITTalentShowAdvancePopUpView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
  //here set the frame height but not working
    view.frame=CGRectMake(0,114,SCREEN_WIDTH,0);
    _advanceMaskPopUpMaskView.advancePopUpView=view;
   [_advanceMaskPopUpMaskView addSubview:view];
    [UIView  animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [view setHeight:390];
            [_advanceMaskPopUpMaskView layoutSubviews];
        }];
```

the subview come out straightly with no animation ,please tell me why,thanks a lot

Comment: [UIView transitionWithView:containerView 
                  duration:0.3 
               options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight //any animation
            animations:^ { [view setHeight:390];
            [_advanceMaskPopUpMaskView layoutSubviews]; }
            completion:nil];

Comment: show the implementation of `setHeight:`

Comment: thanks guys,the problem is that i didn't set clipbounds property ,now it works